# get data from junction table as null if no relation

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables `inputs`, `posts`, and `posts_values`:

[image]

I need to get all inputs with there values, and if value doesn't exist get null instead

like (input, value)

name: David, job:Developer, city:NULL

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question to include sufficient detail to be answerable. Right now you haven't even actually asked anything.

Comment: I've attached an image with the post but I cant see it :/

Comment: learn about LEFT JOINs in SQL

Comment: Learn how to ask question.  More importantly, what have you tried???

Answer (score 2):

You need to `LEFT JOIN` the `inputs` table like this:

```
SELECT i.input_name, pv.value
FROM inputs as i
LEFT JOIN posts        AS p   ON i.form_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN post_values  AS pv  ON pv.b_id   = p.id 
                             AND pv.a_id   = i.id;
```

This will give you:

```
| input_name |     value |
|------------|-----------|
|       name |     David |
|        job | Developer |
|       city |    (null) |
```

- [sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46ed9d/4)

**Note that:**, I assumed that `a_id` on the third table `post_values` is a foreign key for the column `id` in `inputs` table, so that each input name is matched with a value. Otherwise, you might need to make this `a_id` a surrogate key, and add an additional foreign key `input_id`.

---

You need to read about SQL joins and the difference between them, check this for example:

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)